# MySQL database or a simple JSON file which one will be performance efficient and storage efficient?

Tags: mysql, json, performance, processing-efficiency

Let's put concept on table first.
I have voice assistant type of feature for my website.

**How that works?**

- User will type some random phrase and hit enter.
- That phrase will go to A REST API (having AI capability on server) it will decide user
  intent behind that phrase and respond with some relevant text.
- I will be converting that text in to a speech, say mp3 file.

**Flow of converting text to speech:**

- Received text check against a Javascript collection of object
- If phrase found in that then play speech file using path in that object.
- if not found make an Ajax request to local server and call text to speech third party API to receive binary data which can be stored as mp3 file.
- Store path of that file, text and timestamp. (Which can be used in Js collection of object)

**Now the questions are:**

- Should I use MySQL to handle that?
- or should I use simple JSON file for it?
- Which way is efficient from storage and speed point of view?

**Note:**

- if I use MySQL (Please do not suggest to change) then I will need to restrict number of phrase record to 200 entries.
- I am concerned with ease of, minimum time for process and load of that process.
- We have to take amount of time end user will be on wait until this process take place to hear received text in a form of speech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the biggest processors:

- AI
- Text to MP3
- MP3 to text

Any database is *very* far down the list of concerns.  It sounds like your system might execute 1 query-per-second.  Performance issues don't start until 100 or 1000 qps.

As for storage:

- 100-1000 bytes for meta information, versus
- 10K-100K bytes for MP3 (input or output)
- 100GB-1TB for typical low-end server

So, who cares whether MySQL datbase or JSON file is 'bigger'.

Comment: So does not matter whatever I use? it will be costy?

Comment: @Tarik1322 - The software is free; write it both ways and see which feels better.  It is too soon to answer the question; you really need to get deeper into implementation.